# Android view WindowLeaked

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have currently working with some application and exploring things and I encountered this error. This just happened out of nowhere and earlier it seems working fine.

I read some questions related to my problem but I can't relate my codes to them so I am really confused. I'm still beginner so any help would be appreciated.

Logcat

```
4386-4386/com.example.gab.quadrantms E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.gab.quadrantms.Home has leaked window DecorView@abb868f[] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:576)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:363)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:128)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:454)
    at com.example.gab.quadrantms.SurveysFragment$1$1$1.onDataChange(SurveysFragment.java:120)
```

Fragment

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
                                if (myPosition.equals("Project Manager")) {
                                    bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
                                    final View bottomSheetDialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_dialog_layot, null);
                                    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetDialogView);

                                    View viewView = bottomSheetDialogView.findViewById(R.id.view);
                                    View assignView = bottomSheetDialogView.findViewById(R.id.assign);
                                    View deleteView = bottomSheetDialogView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

                    bottomSheetDialog.show();  //THIS LINE WHERE THE ERROR IS POINTING    

                                    if (bottomSheetDialog.isShowing()) {                                          

                                        assignView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                String id = viewHolder.setSurveyID(model.getSurveyID());
                                                String loc = viewHolder.setSurveyLocation(model.getSurveyLocation());
                                                String type = viewHolder.setSurveyType(model.getSurveyType());
                                                String progress = viewHolder.setProgress(model.getProgress());
                                                if (progress.equals("Finished")) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This project is Already Finished.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                } else {
                                                    Intent surveyAssign = new Intent(getActivity(), AssignActivity.class);
                                                    surveyAssign.putExtra("id", id);
                                                    surveyAssign.putExtra("loc", loc);
                                                    surveyAssign.putExtra("type", type);
                                                    surveyAssign.putExtra("progress", progress);
                                                    startActivity(surveyAssign);
                                                    getActivity().finish();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                        deleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                AlertDialog.Builder message = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                                message.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete this Project?").setCancelable(false)
                                                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                                String id = viewHolder.setSurveyID(model.getSurveyID());
                                                                mRemoveDuplicate = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Surveys");
                                                                mRemoveDuplicate.child(id).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Project Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                AlertDialog alert = message.create();
                                                alert.setTitle("Message");
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your **Activity Name** in All **Dialog** where your fragment is run.

Eg.

```
bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this);

AlertDialog.Builder message = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

When does the app crashes? Is it while showing the dialog or while closing the dialog.
If its while closing the dialog, check whether you are dismissing the dialog properly.

Mostly **WindowLeaked** error occurs when you finish the parent activity before dismissing the dialog properly.

Note : If the app crashes during OnClick on **assignView**, finishing the activity here `getActivity().finish();` in OnClickListener might be the problem.